# Can not send data to IO::Socket::INET in conditional statement

Tags: perl

I have an issue communicating with a external system via IO::Socket::Inet.
I try to login and send multiple commands to the system but unfortunately this does'n work if the command print in line 58 is under conditional statement.
The conditional statements in this case is required to handle response data.

```
package Net::Cli::Cisco;

use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Carp;

use Data::Dumper;
$| = 1;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args  = @_;
    my $self  = bless {
        _host     => $args{host}     || carp('No hostname defined'),
        _username => $args{username} || carp('No username defined'),
        _password => $args{password} || carp('No password defined'),
        _logged_in => 0,
    }, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub connect {
    my $self = shift;
    my $host = $self->{_host};
    my $port = 23;

    my $handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto    => "tcp",
        PeerAddr => $host,
        PeerPort => $port,
        Type     => SOCK_STREAM,
        Timeout  => 3
    ) or die "can't connect to port $port on $host: $!";

    my $shc = "\r\n";
    $self->{shc}    = $shc;
    $self->{handle} = $handle;
}

sub getInterface {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->connect;
    my @cmd_list = ( "sh clock", "sh ip int brief" );
    $self->send_cmd(@cmd_list);
}

sub send_cmd {
    my ( $self, @cmd_list ) = @_;
    my $handle = $self->{handle};
    my $response;
    while ( $response = <$handle> ) {

        if ( $response =~ m/^Username:/ ) {
            print "Conditional statements exec done!\n";
            print $handle $self->{_username} . $self->{shc};
        }

        #print $handle $self->{_username} . $self->{shc};
        print $response;
        print $handle $self->{_password} . $self->{shc};
        print $handle "enable" . $self->{shc};
        print $handle $self->{_password} . $self->{shc};
        print $handle "term leng 0" . $self->{shc};

        foreach my $cmd (@cmd_list) {
            print $handle "$cmd" . $self->{shc};
        }
        print $handle "exit" . $self->{shc};

    }

    close($handle);
}

1;

my $x = __PACKAGE__->new(
    "host"     => "1.1.1.1",
    "username" => "user",
    "password" => "pw"
);
$x->getInterface;
```

Well, I can't see why my code is wrong. 
Note: If I recommend line 61 everything working fine. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any indication that `$response =~ m/^Username:/` ever becomes true?

Comment: Yes the the server response include "Username:".

Comment: That is not what I asked about. Do you get the output `Conditional statements exec done!` or not?

Comment: Yes, the output "Conditional statements exec done!" is there!

Comment: How are you determining that print $handle $self->{_username} . $self->{shc}; works outside the conditional block, but doesn't inside it?

Comment: I can determining that over the STOUT. If line number 61 is active I can see that username will send to prompt otherwise only the password from line number 63.

Comment: You are mistaken in your analysis. If the password is being sent without a username, it's because a line that doesn't match `/^Username:/` was encountered.

Answer (score 0):

After comment from ikegami please find working subroutine below:

```
sub send_cmd {
my ( $self, @cmd_list ) = @_;
my $handle = $self->{handle};
my $response;
START: while ( $response = <$handle> ) {
        print $response;
        if ( $response =~ m/[^Username:|^Password:|\$%#:>]/ ) {
            print $handle $self->{_username} . $self->{shc};
            print $handle $self->{_password} . $self->{shc};
            print $handle "enable" . $self->{shc};
            print $handle $self->{_password} . $self->{shc};
            print $handle "term leng 0" . $self->{shc};
            foreach my $cmd (@cmd_list) {
              print $handle "$cmd" . $self->{shc};
            }

            print $handle "exit" . $self->{shc};
        } else {
            goto START;
        }
    }
close($handle);
```